# Elastic Beanstalk instance automatically terminating and launching new ones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk application connected to RDS, and at random times it terminates the current instance, creates a new instance and that makes it lose connection to the database. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more information about why it is losing connection to the database? Is the security group attached to the RDS server only allowing connections from a specific IP address? Since your Elastic Beanstalk instance is in an autoscaling group, and will be replaces any time it fails status checks, you need to design your application to handle that.

Comment: Is the security group attached to the RDS server only allowing connections from a specific IP address? Yes. 
How do I prevent the application from going down? I need it to be in a security group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the security group attached to the RDS server, in the "Source" field, instead of specifying the IP address of the current Elastic Beanstalk server which is subject to change, specify the security group ID that Elastic Beanstalk is assigning to the servers it creates.

This way any EC2 server created by Elastic Beanstalk will be granted access to the RDS instance because the EC2 server will belong to a security group that has been granted access by the RDS security group.